# Accessing key using its value

Tags: c++, stdmap

I am using a `std::map` where both the keys and the values are of type `int` and unique:

```
std::map <int, int> myMap;
myMap[21] = 13;
```

Is it possible to access the key by the value? Something similar to the following:

```
myMap.Key[13];
```

Which would return 21.

Comment: Why do you want to map values back to keys?

Comment: In brief, I am mapping the actual node IDs as the Key and the virtual node IDs as the Value of a large graph. Mostly I need to access it by the key. But at some point, I need to access the key instead. If I can access it by the value, I wouldn't need to maintain another additional array to perform some operation.

Comment: So, basically I just need to access it by the value if possible, don't need to map values back to keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no efficient way of doing this.

You could create a wrapper class with the `std::map` for the key-value pairs, and a `std::multimap` for value-key pairs (or a `std::map` if you can guarantee that the values are unique.) That's more efficient than the next solution, but uses 2x more memory.

The following doesn't use any extra memory, but it is *O(N)* instead of *O(log N)* for maps:

```
const int compare = 13;
auto it = std::find_if(myMap.cbegin(), myMap.cend(), [compare](const auto& value) {
    return value.second == compare;
});

if (it != myMap.cend())
    ; // found key
```